# ng-view not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-view

I have been learning angular.js for a week now and I am trying to  make a practice project.
When I see the HTML code the < div ng-view > part is seen as just < ! -- ngView:  -- >

Below are my files

app/index.html

```
<html data-ng-app="RhythmicWorks">
<head>
    <title>RhytmicWorks Software</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" />
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.videoBG/jquery.videoBG.js"></script>
    <script src="js/videobg.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

  <script src="js/services.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <!-- The following div includes the logo as well as the nav bar -->
    <div data-ng-controller="common" class="common">

        <div class="mainLogo">{{mainLogo}}</div>
      <nav>
            <ul class="fancyNav">
                <li data-ng-repeat="item in navBarItems" id="{{item.id}}">
                    <a href="{{item.href}}">{{item.name}}</a>

                </li>

            </ul>
       </nav>
     </div>
    <div class="content" data-ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

app/js/controllers.js

```
'use strict'

var RhythmicWorksControllers = angular.module('RhythmicWorksControllers',[]);

RhythmicWorksControllers.controller('common',['$scope','navBarData',function($scope,navBarData){

    //$scope.navBarItems = navBarData.query();
    $scope.navBarItems = [{
        "name":"Home",
        "href":"#/home",
        "id":"home"

    },
    {

        "name":"News",
        "href":"#/news",
        "id":"news"

    },
    {

        "name":"About us",
        "href":"#/about",
        "id":"about"

    },
    {

        "name":"Services",
        "href":"#/services",
        "id":"services"

    },
    {

        "name":"Contact us",
        "href":"#/contact",
        "id":"contact"

    }];
    //Main logo text. Can be replaced with a link to the logo

    $scope.mainLogo = "RhythmicWorks";

}]);

RhythmicWorksControllers.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.home = "This is home page";

}]);

RhythmicWorksControllers.controller('newsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.news = "news page";

}]);

RhythmicWorksControllers.controller('contactCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.home = "contact page";

}]);

RhythmicWorksControllers.controller('aboutCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){


    $scope.home = "This is about page";

}]);

RhythmicWorksControllers.controller('servicesCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.home = "This is services page";

}]);
```

app/js/app.js

```
var RhythmicWorks = angular.module('RhythmicWorks',['ngRoute','RhythmicWorksControllers','RhythmicWorksServices']);


RhythmicWorks.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.
            when('/home',{
                templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
                controller: 'homeCtrl'

            }).
            when('/news',{
                templateUrl: 'partials/news.html',
                controller: 'newsCtrl'
            }).
            when('/about',{
                templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
                controller: 'aboutCtrl'
            }).
            when('/services',{
                templateUrl: 'partials/services.html',
                controller: 'servicesCtrl'
            }).
            when('/contact',{
                templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html',
                controller: 'contactCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/home'

            });

    }]);
```

When I click on the links in the navbar, the url changes. If I check the HTML code the  part is seen as just

Note: If I change templateUrl to just template :, it works fine.

I fail to understand the reason why templateUrl is not working correctly. The correct partial html files are present in the partials directory with some random text.

Comment: did you check http request on route click? Debug it . see it it getting resolved or not .

Comment: are you sure you are giving correct path for templateUrl?
To know more, you can do inspect element and watch the console for any errors.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I can see the http request on route click and the correct files are being accessed from the partials. However, <div class="content" data-ng-view></div> is still seen as <!-- ngView:  -->. As soon as I remove 'data-ng-view', the correct class gets applied on the div

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to play video in the background using . As soon as I commented this, it worked